# How do I find a file on USB from linux terminal without searching the .Trash file?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am trying to find a file "myFile.txt" inside a directory dir. This is what I tried:

```
find /usbDir/dir -name 'myFile.txt'
```

I was trying this on an empty USB but it was finding the file. I looked in the .Trash directory and there was a deleted myFile.txt in there so I am assuming this is where it is finding myFile.txt. Is there a way to search for myFile.txt non-recursively? Or is there another way to ignore the .Trash directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-recursively:

```
ls /usbDir/dir/myFile.txt
```

---

Recursively, but ignoring `.Trash`:

```
find /usbDir/dir -name .Trash -prune -o -name 'myFile.txt'
```

Explanation: The `-o` in the middle is an *OR* operator. If I spell out the implied parts, the above is equivalent to:

```
find /usbDir/dir '(' -name .Trash -prune ')' -or '(' -name 'myFile.txt' -print ')'
```

`-prune` tells it to stop searching recursively when it encounters a `.Trash` entry. It prunes the search tree there.

`-print` is the implied action on the right side of the `-or`. It prints matching file names.

The parentheses are optional, as parentheses usually are. They have to be quoted because otherwise the shell would interpret them instead of the `find` command.

Comment: Can protect against off-chance of a dir name `myfile.txt` with `-o -type f -name 'myfile.txt'` (in this case with `"myfile.txt"` that is unlikely, but if name was generic like `"names"`, etc.., it can come in handy)